# Java 8 reverse of grouping by

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to do a simple thing but I'm a bit stuck.
I have the following :

```
Map<Date, Collection<String>>
```

So, for one `Date` I have a list of String (not a unique list).
What I need is to transform this to the following format:

```
List<Object<Date,String>>
```

Each element of the first list could be present several times

```
(Ex of my main list: (date1, string1), (date1, string1), (date2, string2), (date2, string3))
```

I'm trying to do so with java stream but is not so obvious.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is what I have so far

```
    Map<Date, Collection<MyObject>> result = new HashMap<>();
    ......adding elements to the map...

                result.entrySet().stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey(),
                        v -> v.getValue().stream().map( p ->  aggregateProductService.findProduct(customer.getPublicId(), p, setId)).
                                                   filter(Optional::isPresent).
                                                   map(Optional::get).
                                                   collect(toList())
                        )
                ).entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> Pair.of(e.getKey(), s))).
limit(10).
                           collect(toList()).stream().
                          collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getLeft, Collectors.toList()));
```

This piece of code does not compile. I have the following error:

```
Pair::getLeft "non static method cannot be referenced from static context"
```

Comment: It is not clear, Can you provide a constructive example??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .flatmap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> Pair.of(e.getKey(), s)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Great. Do you know how to do the reverse after that ? Actually I need to flatten in order to limit and after that group then like initially. I'm struggling with the groupBy but no success.

Comment: @CC. probably something along the lines of `limit(10).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getLeft, Collectors.toList()))`

Comment: Yes, this is what I've tried but I keep having this error message for Pair::getLeft "non static method cannot be referenced from static context"

Comment: @CC. well without *actual* code, it hard to say exactly what does not work

Comment: @CC. don't get me wrong, but this is a different question right now... you could create a new one and get the desired answer.